# How do I create a generic SortByArray method for c# and mongodb .net driver?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core-3.1, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working with c#, .net core 3.1, latest c# mongo driver but mongo server 4.4 at my company. Unfortunately these are unlikely to change soon. I am trying to re-create the [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) method that is in the new driver version, in c#.

My main problem is I have a very large nested document in the database. Some sub-documents contain arrays. I want to sort based on the contents of the array then when I project I want to add a new field called "currentX" and take the first item from that array.

I was researching and I basically need an unwind/sort/groupby stage back to back for each field I want to add. If I want to add 4 fields this is already a 14+ stage pipeline. This would get too hard to maintain.

I want to create a generic function that performs an unwind/sort/group in place and returns the IMongoQueryable back to perform more calculations on.

This is the sample code I am working with along with the error I am getting as I am stuck:

```
namespace SortByArray
{
    public class CustomObj
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public AnotherObj IntsObj { get; set; }
    }

public class AnotherObj 
    {
        public List<int> Ints { get; set; }
    }
    
    public static class QueryHelpers
    {
        public static IMongoQueryable<TSource> SortByArray<TSource, TSortList, TKey>(this IMongoQueryable<TSource> queryable,
            Expression<Func<HelpMe<TSource>, IEnumerable<HelpMe<TSortList>>>> unwindSelector,
            Expression<Func<HelpMe<TSortList>, TKey>> sortSelector,
            Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource>> resultSelector)
        {
            return queryable
                // Add a constant ID to be able to group with later
                .Select(x => new HelpMe<TSource> { obj = x, id = "1" })

                // unwind
                .SelectMany(unwindSelector)

                // order
                .OrderBy(sortSelector)

                // 
                .GroupBy(x => x.id, resultSelector);
        }

        public class HelpMe<T>
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public T obj { get; set; }
        }
    }
    

    class Program
    {
        private static NewMemberRepo _memberRepo;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _memberRepo = new NewMemberRepo(MongoConnectionSettings.Connector, MongoConnectionSettings.MemberRepositorySettings);
            
            _memberRepo.ExampleMongoQuery()
                .SortByArray(x => x.obj.Ints,
                    x => x.obj.IntsObj.Ints,
// not sure what resultSelector would look like yet, but I want to group it by "HelpMe<T>.id"
);
        }
    }
}
```

I would have gotten it to work except I need the ability to re-group the 2 un-wound int documents based on a key if the documents have no field in common. When I go to group the unwound documents back together, if each field is unique I cannot group them together again. This is why I used the HelpMe class. It will hold the object and a constant key that I could eventually use to group them back up by that string id in the HelpMe class. If I could create an anonymous type that would work without the HelpMe class, but then its hard to pass the anonymous class through the other parameter types. If anyone has a different solution to this problem I would love to hear it.

I essentially want to be able to do:

```
queryable
    .Where()
    .SortByArray(...)
    .SortByArray(...)
    .SortByArray(...)
    .ProjectToDTO(...)
```

instead of having 12 seperate lines for the sortByArray methods.